# MySQL Error when entering large string

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to run a BBCode page in my DataBase, and what I want to happen is the administrators are able to edit the BBCode and it can be changed on the live site - But for some reason I keep getting a error with the message:

```
1 row affected 
Warning: #1366 Incorrect String Value:
'\xE2\x80\x8BRec...' for colum 'body' at row 1
```

The string I'm parsing to the DataBase has `[`'s and `]`'s in them, as it is BBCode as well as normal text, other than that it's normal text and numbers.

I went and checked what `type` I have set for the `body` in the table and it was set to `text`, and I thought that was what you were supposed to set if you are using large amounts of text (also the amount is set to nothing)

Comment: Is it possible that the database/table was defined as UTF-8 but the string is not a valid UTF-8 value?

Comment: I haven't declared to use a specific type of encoding or anything, how would I know if I have or not?

Comment: `show create table` and `show create database`